# terminationGracePeriodSeconds in kind pod vs kind deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to set a grace shutdown period for my pods. I found out you can add a field called `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` to the helm charts to set the period. I then looked for example and crossed upon these:

https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubernetes-best-practices-terminating-with-grace

In the above link they define the value in a `kind: pod` template.

https://pracucci.com/graceful-shutdown-of-kubernetes-pods.html

In the above link they define the value in a `kind: deployment` template.

Is there a difference between the 2 kinds in regard to where I define this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference between the 2 kinds in regard to where I define this value?

A `Deployment` has a field `template:` and that is actually a `PodTemplate` (most structure of a `Pod`) that includes the `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` property.

A good way to check documentations for fields is to use `kubectl explain`.

E.g.

```
kubectl explain Deployment.spec.template.spec
```

and

```
kubectl explain Pod.spec
```

Comment: What I learn from this is that both has terminationGracePeriodSeconds and the kubectl explains returns the same documentation. Still not sure if there's actually a difference. What is kind pod used for if its already defined in the kind deployment?

Comment: Kubernetes creates Pods from the `template:` in a Deployment; you don't usually create them yourself.

Comment: @DavidMaze Then what is that example with kind pod?

Comment: @YonatanNir if you use `Deployment` then that is the manifest you are interacting with. It uses the podTemplate-part of `Deployment` to create its Pods (for each replica). When using `Deployment`, you don’t interact with the `Pod` manifest directly, only in-direct via Deployment.

Comment: @Jonas Then is it correct to say that using deployment means I will set this settings for ALL pods and if I had used the kind pod, I could set different values for different pods?

Comment: @YonatanNir yes that is correct. But if you use "kind Pod" - they are not managed by a controller. When using "kind Deployment" the pods are managed by a controller, to always be running the number of replicas that you have specified, e.g. if a Pod is crashed, a new one will be started.